# In Debezium add to the ExtractNewRecordState a specific field from the "before" record

Tags: debezium

I want to extract only the new record from a record update/create, so I am using:

```
"transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
```

But I would like also to add a `status` field from the old record. I, of course, don't want to add the whole unnecessary `before` record.

Trying to do:

```
"transforms.unwrap.add.fields": "before.status",
```

doesn't work, since I am getting

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected field name:
> before.status

Is there a way to add a specific field to the message model?

Comment: have you tried putting it as "value.before.status"?

Comment: @BünyaminŞentürk It does not work. We are not using `value` in this config. 
For example, in order to use `op` we write `op` and not `value.op` as we do in the `transforms.filter.condition`.
I believe I can't really use `transforms.unwrap.add.fields` for my needs since it is only for [metadata fields](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/configuration/event-flattening.html#_adding_metadata_fields_to_the_message).